# Installing CNProg on shared hosting (1and1)?

Tags: shared-hosting, 1and1

I have shared hosting on 1and1.

I have shell access but don't have root access.

Is it possible. To install CNProg, (Which is a SO Clone in Python) on that kind of hosting?

If not, can I use Ubuntu with LAMP and Python?

I have tried, but am at a loss on how to get it done.

If anyone has installed CNProg I would appreciate your help.

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and guess that you won't find much help in this forum but I went ahead and cleaned up the question and tags anyway just in case someone wants to take a stab at it.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using OSQA (www.osqa.net)? As far as I know, CNProg is no longer under active development and has been superseded by OSQA.

Answer (score 1):

CNProg is based on Django and Python, which are not particularly easy to install on shared hosts like 1and1.com, but it's possible. And it doesn't require root access--you can install everything in your (web hosts') home directory.

Here's one good set of instructions: http://www.codekoala.com/blog/2008/installing-django-shared-hosting-site5/

Hope that gets you on your way!